# "[error] Input file not found!" Docker OSRM

Tags: docker, osrm

I will preface this by saying I am a newbie.

Nonetheless, I am trying to run OSRM with Docker. I have tried to run the first OSRM backend docker command they list on their github:

> docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf

A thing to note is that I changed
This: ${PWD} from the original command in the OSRM backend
To this: %cd%"
Because I run docker on a windows 10 not Linux.

I also used a Geofabrik cutout that is in Denmark instead of Berlin (which they use in the demo version on Github).

Here is what I ran in the commando prompt:

> docker run -t -v "%cd%":/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/foot.lua /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf

As you can see on the attached photo it starts pulling the "osrm/osrm-backend: latest". But I get the error message: "[error] Input file /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf not found!"Which is odd because I have denmark-latest.osm.pbf stored in c -->docker -->data and also a copy in a folder on my desktop called osrm-backend-master where the profiles are in (foot.lua in my case) and in a folder called "data" I have stored denmark-latest.osm.pbf.

A few posts mention "shared drives" options as a solution to my problem but in my settings I don't have a "shared drive" option - which I think is because I run on WSL 2 (though I am not sure about that one).

Picture of CMD prompt:

[image: CMD prompt]

Can any of you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Mads! I have this issue now. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

follow steps and solve problem

1. `mkdir data`
2. `cd data`
3. `docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data/" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error a while ago. I tried something like this but I don't really remember:

```
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf
```

Also, you can add an extra "/" after first "data appearance" such as:

```
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data/" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/denmark-latest.osm.pbf
```

Or you can enter to your new `data` folder and run any of those commands.

Answer (score 0):

greetings and I hope you are well.

I had a similar error, and it was because I omitted part of the installation command, remember to follow the installation instructions to the letter.

In my case, I omitted the following part of the command: ':/data.osm.pbf'

I share the site commands:
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/

Download map source file:

```
wget yourfile-map.pbf
```

Create docker volume:

```
docker volume create openstreetmap-data
```

Create container:

```
time docker run -v yourfile-map.pbf:/data.osm.pbf -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:1.3.10 import
```

Start the server:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main -d overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:1.3.10 run
```